I want to change the track and title of mp3 files using their ID3 Tag data in all sub directories too not just the folder I am in
I want to change the track and title of mp3 files using their ID3 Tag data in all sub directories too not just the folder I am in.
To change track and title in a single folder sometimes kid3-cli or eyeD3 works for me but, I am willing to try other suggestions (along with kid3-cli or eyeD3 ):
$ kid3-cli -c 'fromtag "%{track}-%{title}" 1' *.mp3

$ find . -name \*.mp3 -execdir eyeD3 --rename '$track:num-$title' *.mp3 {} \;


How about ffmpeg?
Well, ffprobe actually, but it's part of the package.
#!/bin/bash

set -o noclobber # just a precaution

get_metadata() {
  local song="$1"
  local song_track=$(ffprobe -v error -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format_tags=track "$song" | awk '{print $1}')
  local song_title=$(ffprobe -v error -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format_tags=title "$song")
  song_track=$(echo "$song_track" | awk '{printf "%02d\n", $0}') # pad track number to ensure it's two digits
  echo "$song_track" "$song_title"
}

# list mp3s with their full paths
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name "*.mp3" > /tmp/my_mp3_list
readarray -t list_mp3s < /tmp/my_mp3_list

for song in "${list_mp3s[@]}"; do
  IFS=' ' read -r song_track song_title <<< "$(get_metadata "$song")"
  file_name="${song_track}-${song_title}.mp3"
  file_name=$(echo "$file_name" | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g') # sanitize bad characters
  dir_name=$(dirname "$song")
  new_file_path="$dir_name/$file_name"
  mv -- "$song" "$new_file_path"
  echo "Renamed '$(basename -s .mp3 "$song").mp3' to '$(basename -s .mp3 "$new_file_path").mp3'"
done

rm tmp/my_mp3_list

exit 0

Save as: rename_from_id3.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x rename_from_id3.sh
Usage: ./rename_from_id3.sh
Run from the .mp3 directory.  All files in that directory will be renamed, recursively.

Thank you and yes it worked!

Thank you and yes it worked!
Anything that did not have a title was named 00-. and is easy to find.
It missed some but they can be cleaned up manually.
Many songs #08 and #09 often get labeled 00 too but they clean up nicely too manually.
For a 700GB folder this was a lifesaver. Thank you again.

@GeneTyle Likely too late to matter, but I figured out the 08 & 09 issue.  prinf was throwing some octet error, and wrapping the printf with awk solved it.

What would that look like?

I updated the script.  Changing the number padding to awk '{printf "%02d\n", $0}' fixed the problem with #08 and #09.
